# NGINX and TRAEFIK staticfiles are not working with HTTPS in production

Tags: django, docker, nginx, https, traefik

I'm developing a website for my association [Here](https://appli.amis-simserhof.fr/). It uses Django 3.0.7 and PostgreSQL. I follow this [tutorial](https://testdriven.io/blog/dockerizing-django-with-postgres-gunicorn-and-nginx/) to make it works in good condition in development and in production.

In development mode all is good, site is working perfectly, static files and media files are served by the Django built-in web server.

I test the "vanilla" (coming from the tutorial) production on my local machine it works too. But the tutorial is not complete for me so after completing it, I decided to adapt the code to fit my needs. As I follow the tutorial I created a new docker-compose and a new dockerfile for production. But there are 2 differences between the tutorial and the site I want to set in production:

1. I want to Use TREAFIK to route the traffic on different URL (appli.amis-simserhof.fr) because I will have other projects in the future on the same server with others subdomains..
2. I want to secure the website using HTTPS. So I use CERTBOT (let's encrypt) to generate certificates. I add this certificates to TREAFFIK in order to use HTTPS and it works.

So I adapted the docker-compose file with my new stuff :

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  **traefik:
    image: traefik:v1.7.12
    command: [ 
      "--loglevel=INFO",
      "--api",
      "--docker",
      "--docker.domain=amis-simserhof.fr",
      "--entrypoints=name:https address::443 tls:/etc/certs/fullchain.pem,/etc/certs/privkey.pem",
      "--entrypoints=name:http address::80 redirect.entrypoint:https",
      ]
    ports:
      - 80:80               # http
      - 443:443             # https
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
      - /etc/letsencrypt/live/amis-simserhof.fr/fullchain.pem:/etc/certs/fullchain.pem
      - /etc/letsencrypt/live/amis-simserhof.fr/privkey.pem:/etc/certs/privkey.pem**
  web:
    image: registry.gitlab.com/guillaumekoenigtncy/aas-web:latest
    command: gunicorn aas.wsgi:application --bind 0.0.0.0:8000
    expose:
      - 8000
    volumes:
      - static_volume:/home/app/web/staticfiles
      - media_volume:/home/app/web/mediafiles
    environment:
      - DEBUG=0
      - SECRET_KEY=change_me
      - DJANGO_ALLOWED_HOSTS=localhost appli.amis-simserhof.fr
      - SQL_ENGINE=django.db.backends.postgresql
      - SQL_DATABASE=postgres
      - SQL_USER=postgres
      - SQL_PASSWORD=postgres
      - SQL_HOST=db
      - SQL_PORT=5432
      - DATABASE=postgres
    labels:
      - traefik.frontend.rule=HostRegexp:appli.amis-simserhof.fr
      - traefik.frontend.entryPoints=https
    depends_on:
      - db
  db:
    image: postgres:12.0-alpine
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=postgres
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
  **nginx:
    image: registry.gitlab.com/guillaumekoenigtncy/aas-nginx:latest
    volumes:
      - static_volume:/home/app/web/staticfiles
      - media_volume:/home/app/web/mediafiles
    expose:
      - 80
      - 443
    depends_on:
      - web**
      
volumes:
  postgres_data:
  static_volume:
  media_volume:
```

I also created a dockerfile and a config file for nginx :

```
FROM nginx:1.19.0

RUN rm /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d
```

```
upstream website {
    server web:8000;
}

server {

    listen 80; 
    listen [::]:80;

    access_log off;
    server_name appli.amis-simserhof.fr;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://website;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }

    location /staticfiles/ {
        alias /home/app/web/staticfiles/;
    }

    location /mediafiles/ {
        alias /home/app/web/mediafiles/;
    }

}
```

**The problem is that now static files are not served in production (I got a 404)**. When I set the DEBUG to True in the setting.py of the project files are served sot that means static files are present in the correct folder that I have set in the settings.

```
STATIC_URL = "/staticfiles/"
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "staticfiles")

MEDIA_URL = "/mediafiles/"
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "mediafiles")
```

In production, I have correctly run the `python manage.py collectstatic` command. I look inside both containers, ngnix and web, and in both the files are present in the correct directory.

So I conclude my configuration is not working but when I made changes in it, I saw this changes in the nginx logs of the containers. There are no errors...

I try everything during the last 2 days: set the ssl in the nginx config and remove it from traefik (site is not accessible), expose or not ports 80 and 443 in nginx or traefik (conflicts on open ports or too many redirect error), add or remove / at the end or at the beginning of blocks or alias in nginx configuration (change nothing), etc.

If you have any hint or tips I would be really grateful...

Have a nice day :)

Comment: One of my former collegue has the same issue to expose static files with Django behind Traefik. I think he put the static files in NGINX behind Traefik with a rule Path('staticfiles')

Comment: I tried but it doesn't work...

Answer (score 2):

I'am was able do define static path with following nginx service configuration:

```
version: '3.7'

services:
    server:
        container_name: dj
        build:
            context: ./server/project/
        restart: unless-stopped
        expose:
            - 8000
        volumes:
            - static_volume:/app/staticfiles
            - media_volume:/app/media
        command: gunicorn project.wsgi:application --bind 0.0.0.0:8000
        networks:
           - web
    nginx:
        container_name: nginx
        build:
            context: ./
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
        restart: unless-stopped
        volumes:
            - static_volume:/app/staticfiles
            - media_volume:/app/media
        labels:
           - "traefik.enable=true"
           - "traefik.http.routers.${SERVICE}.rule=(Host(`${DOMAIN_NAME}`) && PathPrefix(`/static`)) || (Host(`${DOMAIN_NAME}`) && PathPrefix(`/media`))"
           - "traefik.http.routers.${SERVICE}.tls.certresolver=letsEncrypt"
           - "traefik.http.routers.${SERVICE}.entrypoints=web-secure"
           - "traefik.http.services.${SERVICE}.loadbalancer.server.port=80"
        depends_on:
            - server
        networks:
           - web

volumes:
    static_volume:
    media_volume:

networks:
   web:
      external: true
```

Note this line:

```
- "traefik.http.routers.static-http.rule=Host(`ex.example.com`) && PathPrefix(`/static`)"
```

change the `ex.example.com` to you domain

Here is part of my configuration, The "server" part is not completed yet

**UPDATE**
To use the same static files between django and nginx use following nxing configuration:

```
#default.conf

server {
    listen                      80;
    server_name                 _;

    ignore_invalid_headers      on;

    location / {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index index.html;
        default_type application/javascript;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;
    }

    location /static {
        autoindex on;
        alias /app/staticfiles/;
    }

    location /media {
        autoindex on;
        alias /app/media/;
    }

    access_log                  /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log                   /var/log/nginx/error.log;
}
```

**Also note** that I've updated docker-compose file and added Dockerfile below:

```
#Dockerfile
FROM nginx:1.19.1-alpine

COPY nginx/default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
```

So your Project-Structure should look like:

```
Project-root/
  |-server/
  |-nginx/
  |   |-default.conf
  |-Dockerfile
  |-docker-compose.yml
```

Comment: I tried to use directly it doesn't work. I tried to change HTTP by HTTPS and it doesn't work too... Maybe my configuration of nginx is not good or my docker-compose. I don't know.

In your example you don't have a volume to share static files between Django and nginx.  How do you manage them after you collect the static files in the Django container ?